# Flutter app, ListView.builder pictures errors at first run. Need restart app (ListView.builder and image_picker)

Tags: android, flutter, listview

I discover Flutter, and I encounter a problem during the development of my app.

I add a miscellaneous item in my database, along with data and a link to a photograph taken via **image_picker**.
I display the list of these miscellaneous items on the application home using a **ListView.builder**.

When the application opens for the first time, an error occurs not finding the images.
I have to restart app to avoid the error.

I must be missing something, can someone help me?

This is the function that processes the image capture and saves it.

```
Future getImage() async {
  final PickedFile pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  final Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  final String path = directory.path;
  final String filename = basename(pickedFile.path);
  final File newFile = await moveFile(File(pickedFile.path), '$path/$filename');
  setState(() {
    _image = newFile;
  });
}
```

Here for display the list.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: widget.markers.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: AssetImage(widget.markers[index].image),
    ),
    title: Text('title')
  );
})
```

And for the first run have error :

```
**
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.flutter_locate_reminder/files/89d7c94f-072a-4308-88d7-2d24b8ca744f9044594904088454133.jpg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:225
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:668
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:651
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:504
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.flutter_locate_reminder/files/89d7c94f-072a-4308-88d7-2d24b8ca744f9044594904088454133.jpg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#1fb35(), name: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.flutter_locate_reminder/files/89d7c94f-072a-4308-88d7-2d24b8ca744f9044594904088454133.jpg", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

it doesn't seem to find the images right away.

Thank for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Image.file(File file)` instead of AssetImage.

`````
  itemCount: widget.markers.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: Image.file(widget.markers[index].image),
    ),
    title: Text('title')
  );
})````
`````

Answer (score 0):

to get image

```
final image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
setState(() {
  _image = File(image.path);
});
```

to show image

```
backgroundImage: Image.file(_image),
```

I think this is enough to get and show the image.

Comment: Thank for ur help ! 

But i can't assign backgroundImage: Image.file(_image)
Same with image.file(File(_image));

backrgoundImage need ImageProvider not a file.

So, i can resolve my problem with : 

backgroundImage: FileImage(File(_image))

Thank u bro for right track ;)